# How to write only a subset of fields using DictReader and DictWriter

Tags: python, csv

CSV testfile called Sample.csv contains:

```
Brand, Price, Weight, Type
brand1, 6.05, 3.2, orange
brand2, 8.05, 5.2, orange
brand3, 6.54, 4.2, orange
brand1, 6.05, 3.2, pear
brand2, 7.05, 3.6, pear
brand3, 7.45, 3.9, pear
brand1, 5.45, 2.7, apple
brand2, 6.05, 3.2, apple
brand3, 6.43, 3.5, apple
brand4, 7.05, 3.9, apple
brand1, 8.05, 4.2, plum
brand2, 3.05, 2.2, plum
```

My code is:

```
import csv
headers = ['Brand','Price','Type']

with open('sample.csv', newline='') as rf:
    reader = csv.DictReader(rf, delimiter=',',fieldnames=headers)
    with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as wf:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(wf, delimiter=',', extrasaction='ignore', fieldnames=headers)
        writer.writerow(dict((fn,fn) for fn in writer.fieldnames))
        for row in reader:
           print(row)
           writer.writerow(row)
```

I'm only trying to get Brand, Price, Type into the output file but am getting:

```
Brand,Price,Type
Brand, Price, Weight
brand1, 6.05, 3.2
brand2, 8.05, 5.2
brand3, 6.54, 4.2
brand1, 6.05, 3.2
brand2, 7.05, 3.6
brand3, 7.45, 3.9
brand1, 5.45, 2.7
brand2, 6.05, 3.2
brand3, 6.43, 3.5
brand4, 7.05, 3.9
brand1, 8.05, 4.2
brand2, 3.05, 2.2
```

Why am I getting the Weight field in the output, not the Type field?

Note that the line writer.writerow(dict((fn,fn) for fn in writer.fieldnames)) was added for debugging, intentially printing out the header twice.

Comment: We're more able to help if we see a small sample of the input files—small enough to recreate the problem without excessive baggage.

Comment: the input file, sample.csv is shown at the top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that you have entered the column names `Brand, Price, Weight` in `headers` will not make `DictReader` parse and return just those columns from the source file. It will just assign the columns it finds in the file to those keys - effectively, you could name them `First, Second, Third`, and the result will be the same.

You have two options:

### Use the source header row

Use the fact that you have a header row, let `DictReader` name the keys based on it, and write just the ones you want:

```
import csv
headers = ['Brand', 'Price', 'Type']

with open('sample.csv') as rf:
    reader = csv.DictReader(rf, delimiter=',', skipinitialspace=True)
    with open('output.csv', 'w') as wf:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(wf, delimiter=',', extrasaction='ignore', fieldnames=headers)
        writer.writeheader()
        for row in reader:
            print(row)
            writer.writerow(row)
```

### Explicitly set the columns (in source & output)

Be explicit what are the columns in the source, and explicit what you want in the output - use two lists:

```
import csv
present_headers = ['Brand', 'Price', 'Weight', 'Type']
desired_headers = ['Brand', 'Price', 'Type']

with open('sample.csv') as rf:
    reader = csv.DictReader(rf, delimiter=',', fieldnames=present_headers, skipinitialspace=True)
    with open('output.csv', 'w') as wf:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(wf, delimiter=', ', extrasaction='ignore', fieldnames=desired_headers)
        writer.writeheader()
        next(reader, None)   #to skip writing the header row from the source
        for row in reader:
            # print(row)
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Given the sample  in your question, both options produce equivalent results.

Couple of remarks - the sample in the question has the delimiter `,` followed by space - both in the headers, and in the data rows. If it is really there (not a copy & paste mistake), the option `skipinitialspace=True` in the reader will get rid of it - otherwise it becomes part of the data in the column.

The other is there's no need to manually construct the header row for the DictWriter - that's what the `writerheader()` method is for.

Finally, you can see in option 2 there's the call `next(reader, None)` just before writing the data - its purpose is for the reader to yield the first row, as it is now just a normal (not header) one, and we don't want to duplicate it in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Using Python 3.5.2, I was able to duplicate your issue exactly, so I'll assume this is your version as well.

Your issue is that the DictReader object needs to match the headers in `sample.csv`, else `reader` will not contain the correct data to begin with. Because `len(headers)` doesn't match the number of columns in `sample.csv`, DictReader is mapping the first `len(headers)` columns to your `reader` keys, which is why 'Type' and 'Weight' are mapped to each other in your `output.csv`. While you could duplicate the `sample.csv` headers in code and differentiate between the input and output headers for DictReader and DictWriter, respectively, I recommend letting the CSV handle the correct header mapping. This is done by simply removing `fieldnames=headers` from the DictReader instantiation.

Now that you're letting DictReader use the `sample.csv` headers as keys, you'll need to keep your line for debugging as a permanent fixture (although the built-in `writer.writeheader()` is a more concise variation). Also, because `sample.csv` contains spaces before each value, each `header` element except the first will need to have a leading space to match the keys in `reader`.

Your final code might look like:

```
import csv
headers = ['Brand',' Price',' Type']

with open('sample.csv', newline='') as rf:
    reader = csv.DictReader(rf, delimiter=',')
    with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as wf:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(wf, delimiter=',', extrasaction='ignore', fieldnames=headers)
        writer.writeheader()
        for row in reader:
           print(row)     
           writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: The `skipinitialspace=True` flag as remarked from @Todor is magic. Then you no longer need spaces in `headers` elements.

Comment: Thank you-- this was also very helpful